# Does indexing arrays with temporary objects leak memory?

Tags: roblox

For example, if I have something like this:

```
Array = {}
RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player)
    local Part = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
    Array[Part] = Player.UserId
    wait(10)
    Part:Destroy()
end)
```

Will that leak memory? Will it automatically remove the index for that part once it detects that it's been removed? Or do I need to manually set it to nil when removing it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, yes it will, you initialize / localize the Table outside the scope therefor anything cached / stored inside it won't be garbage collected, part itself still get's deleted although Table itself will still contain its data.

Easy way to prove my answer is by iterating through the array after the scope ends and as you will see it will still print out the "Part" instance.

**--> Code**

```
local Table= {}

local function CachePart()
    --> Create a new scope
    
    local Part = Instance.new("Part")
    
    Table[Part] = Part
    Part:Destroy()
end

CachePart()

for i, v in next, Table do
    print(i,v) -- prints Part, Part
end
```

Although the instance's Data is still saved it does not mean it can be used, trying to parent it will error.

**--> How to fix**

Either you localize your Table within the scope or manually remove it after by doing:

```
Table[index] = nil

--or

table.remove(Table, Index) 

if your index is unknown you can use table.find 

local Index = table.find(Table, Value)
```